# Pandas : Copy recent date's data for missing days

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in the following format in a pandas Dataframe where the index is data. This is financial data for which certain date's data can be missing. I need to fill in the missing day's data with the most recent date's (prior to date of interest) data. Also, I need to fill in only for week days. How do I accomplish this in pandas? A simple method would be to iterate through each row (in order of date) while keeping the most recent data and copying into a new dataframe. IF a date is missing, most recent available data can be copied. Are there better alternatives?

```
               Open    Close     High      Low    WeekDay
Date                                                     
2018-03-12  1449.80  1433.60  1450.00  1423.60     Monday
2018-03-13  1438.60  1410.80  1439.85  1402.00    Tuesday
2018-03-14  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00  Wednesday
2018-03-19  1340.00  1317.30  1345.00  1310.00     Monday
2018-03-20  1319.90  1304.70  1326.00  1297.00    Tuesday
2018-03-21  1314.80  1297.00  1314.80  1293.10  Wednesday
2018-03-22  1309.50  1289.80  1313.95  1275.00   Thursday
2018-03-23  1276.00  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00     Friday
2018-03-27  1285.55  1274.95  1309.95  1267.25    Tuesday
2018-03-28  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  Wednesday
2018-04-03  1300.00  1283.15  1300.05  1277.20    Tuesday
2018-04-04  1294.90  1271.35  1300.00  1267.55  Wednesday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) for all columns without `WeekDay` and last add this columns by [`DatetimeIndex.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday_name.html):

(following solution is filling in all missing days including week ends)

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['WeekDay'])
df = df[cols].resample('D').ffill()
df['WeekDay'] = df.index.weekday_name

print (df)
               Open    Close     High      Low    WeekDay
Date                                                     
2018-03-12  1449.80  1433.60  1450.00  1423.60     Monday
2018-03-13  1438.60  1410.80  1439.85  1402.00    Tuesday
2018-03-14  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00  Wednesday
2018-03-15  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00   Thursday
2018-03-16  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00     Friday
2018-03-17  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00   Saturday
2018-03-18  1413.00  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00     Sunday
2018-03-19  1340.00  1317.30  1345.00  1310.00     Monday
2018-03-20  1319.90  1304.70  1326.00  1297.00    Tuesday
2018-03-21  1314.80  1297.00  1314.80  1293.10  Wednesday
2018-03-22  1309.50  1289.80  1313.95  1275.00   Thursday
2018-03-23  1276.00  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00     Friday
2018-03-24  1276.00  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00   Saturday
2018-03-25  1276.00  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00     Sunday
2018-03-26  1276.00  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00     Monday
2018-03-27  1285.55  1274.95  1309.95  1267.25    Tuesday
2018-03-28  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  Wednesday
2018-03-29  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00   Thursday
2018-03-30  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00     Friday
2018-03-31  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00   Saturday
2018-04-01  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00     Sunday
2018-04-02  1284.50  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00     Monday
2018-04-03  1300.00  1283.15  1300.05  1277.20    Tuesday
2018-04-04  1294.90  1271.35  1300.00  1267.55  Wednesday
```

EDIT:

(following solution is for restricting filling process for only week days)

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['WeekDay'])
df = df[cols].resample('D').ffill()
df['WeekDay'] = df.index.weekday_name
df = df[~df['WeekDay'].isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
print (df)
              Close     High      Low     Open    WeekDay
Date                                                     
2018-03-12  1433.60  1450.00  1423.60  1449.80     Monday
2018-03-13  1410.80  1439.85  1402.00  1438.60    Tuesday
2018-03-14  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00  1413.00  Wednesday
2018-03-15  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00  1413.00   Thursday
2018-03-16  1390.25  1413.00  1381.00  1413.00     Friday
2018-03-19  1317.30  1345.00  1310.00  1340.00     Monday
2018-03-20  1304.70  1326.00  1297.00  1319.90    Tuesday
2018-03-21  1297.00  1314.80  1293.10  1314.80  Wednesday
2018-03-22  1289.80  1313.95  1275.00  1309.50   Thursday
2018-03-23  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00  1276.00     Friday
2018-03-26  1277.90  1288.80  1270.00  1276.00     Monday
2018-03-27  1274.95  1309.95  1267.25  1285.55    Tuesday
2018-03-28  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  1284.50  Wednesday
2018-03-29  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  1284.50   Thursday
2018-03-30  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  1284.50     Friday
2018-04-02  1294.65  1300.00  1273.00  1284.50     Monday
2018-04-03  1283.15  1300.05  1277.20  1300.00    Tuesday
2018-04-04  1271.35  1300.00  1267.55  1294.90  Wednesday
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I restrict it to only weekdays (updated the question).

Comment: @dineshdileep - Do you think remove `Saturday` and `Sunday`? Please check last edit

Comment: Thanks. Just a note weekday_name has been deprecated and is now day_name()

Comment: Also you can use B instead of D and then df[~df['WeekDay'].isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])] isn't required.